# uploading to the wrong URL? when integrate Google drive and youtube API in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, youtube-api, google-drive-api

I have tried to integrate Google driver and youtube API in single app. Integrated both api successfully for uploading videos.

I logged in using google drive and uploaded the video to google drive successfully. With the same login when I try to upload videos to youtube I am getting below error.

The same scenario occurs vice-versa also.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unexpected response data
>   (uploading to the wrong URL?)'

The below is the code used for authentication.

```
if(@"youtube" isEqualToString:TYPE)
{ 
        self.youtubeService = [[GTLServiceYouTube alloc] init];
        self.youtubeService.authorizer =
        [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                                       clientID:kClientID
                                                                                   clientSecret:kClientSecret];


     if (![self isAuthorized]) {
          // Not yet authorized, request authorization and push the login UI onto the navigation stack.
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:[self createAuthController] animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        //My Code

    }
}
if(@"drive" isEqualToString:TYPE)
{ 
    self.driveService = [[GTLServiceDriver alloc] init];
    self.driveService.authorizer =[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                                       clientID:kClientID
                                                                                   clientSecret:kClientSecret];


    if (![self isAuthorizedDriver]) {
     // Not yet authorized, request authorization and push the login UI onto the navigation stack.
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:[self createAuthControllerDriver] animated:YES];
     }
    else
    {
        //My Code

     }
}


// Creates the auth controller for authorizing access to YouTube.

- (GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)createAuthController
{
    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authController;

    authController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeYouTube
                                                                clientID:kClientID
                                                            clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                                        keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                delegate:self
                                                        finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
    return authController;
}
// Handle completion of the authorization process, and updates the YouTube service
// with the new credentials.
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)authResult
                 error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error != nil) {
        [Utils showAlert:@"Authentication Error" message:error.localizedDescription];
        self.youtubeService.authorizer = nil;
    } else {
        self.youtubeService.authorizer = authResult;
    }
}



// Creates the auth controller for authorizing access to Google drive.
- (GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)createAuthControllerDriver
{
    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authController;

    authController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive
                                                                clientID:kClientID
                                                            clientSecret:kClientSecret
                                                        keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                delegate:self
                                                        finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
    return authController;
}
// Handle completion of the authorization process, and updates the Drive service
// with the new credentials.
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuthDriver:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)authResult
                 error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error != nil) {
        [Utils showAlert:@"Authentication Error" message:error.localizedDescription];
        self.driveService.authorizer = nil;
    } else {
        self.driveService.authorizer = authResult;
    }
}


//  check if user is authorized
- (BOOL)isAuthorized {
    return [((GTMOAuth2Authentication *)self.youtubeService.authorizer) canAuthorize];
}

- (BOOL)isAuthorizedDriver {
    return [((GTMOAuth2Authentication *)self.driveService.authorizer) canAuthorize];
}
```

I checked the url for authorization current scope and it is same as the credentials I used for login.
I think this might be the issue, Can some one point out how to solve it. That is with single login I need access both apis.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine to have same OAuth2, with both scopes defined, and both services initialized from there. I can not see the whole code here, but you could be mistakingly reusing one of the parameters.

Here's a full sample for youtube upload. Comparing this with your code may help:
https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-iOS